# Escaping `\\` in VS Code in snippets

Tags: escaping, visual-studio-code

I'm writing a tex snippet in VS code. The following is one of my example:

```
"Input a multiline eqn": {
    "prefix": "eqnmultiline",
    "body": [
        "\\[",
        "\t\\begin{array}{lcl}",
        "\t\t ${1:foo} & = & ${2:foo} \\\\",
        "\t\t & = & ${3:foo} \\\\",
        "\t\t & = & ${4:foo} \\\\",
        "\t\\end{array}",
        "\\]",
        "$0"
    ],
    "description": "Input a multiline eqn"
}
```

However, only one `\` at the end of line will be output when I insert the above snippet to some demo.tex.

Output:

```
\[
    \begin{array}{lcl}
         foo & = & foo \
         & = & foo \
         & = & foo \
    \end{array}
\]
```

And I'm expecting a `\\` macro comes out at the end of line of equations rather than a `\`.

[VS Code Snippet Grammer](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_grammar) only explains escaping `\` using  another `\`. Any methods to escape `\\` correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have posted this issue on the github homepage of the VSCode project. And I get `jrieken` 's response saying :

> This dupe #32020 (comment) but in short this is the problem
>
> In TextMate you can but must not escape a backslash with a backslash,
>   so to insert 1 backslash have either `\` or `\\`
>
> In JSON you must escape a
>   backslash with another backslash, so to insert 1 backslash have either
>   `\\` or `\\\\`, to insert 2 `\\\\\\\\`